# Uncaught error when injecting $document in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-head

I am new to `Angular.js`. I am trying to inject `$document` to retrieve the `<head>` element in the HTML document:

```
app.run(function($scope, $document) {

    var headRetr = $document.find("head");

    if ( headRetr === null ) {
        console.log("head not found");
    } else {
        console.log("head found");
    }

});
```

When I start my application and open the console, I see an error message:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope(anonymous function)
@ angular.js:38(anonymous function)
@ angular.js:4255d
@ angular.js:4402(anonymous function)
@ angular.js:4260d
@ angular.js:4402e
@ angular.js:4434(anonymous function)
@ angular.js:4265n
@ angular.js:336db
@ angular.js:4265d
@ angular.js:1621zc
@ angular.js:1642Yd
@ angular.js:1536(anonymous function)
@ angular.js:28289a
@ angular.js:2989c
@ angular.js:3264
```

What am I doing wrong? I am on `angular 1.4.1`.

Comment: There's a URL in your error. Did you even think to go to that URL and see what it said?

Comment: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `.run` to this:

```
app.run(function($document) {

});
```

There's no `$scope` available in `.run`. You're not even using it.

Comment: You can though inject `$rootScope` if you need it, just FYI to OP